# Flutter admob Remove ads by IAP

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

Hi I'm showing firebase admob banner and interstial ad with this way.It shows ads from firebase admob.Its signed to firebase

```
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class AdvertService {
  static final AdvertService _instance = AdvertService._internal();
  factory AdvertService() => _instance;
  MobileAdTargetingInfo _targetingInfo;

  final String _bannerAd = Platform.isAndroid
      ? 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx1/5xxxxxxxx'
      : 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx1/2xxxxxxxx';
  final String _interAd = Platform.isAndroid
      ? 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx1/1xxxxxxxx'
      : 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx1/6xxxxxxxx';
  // FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appId);

  AdvertService._internal() {
    //_targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo( testDevices: <String>["54a0a4f2"]);
    _targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo();
  }
  showBanner() {
    print(_bannerAd);
    BannerAd banner = BannerAd(
        adUnitId: _bannerAd,
        size: AdSize.smartBanner,
        targetingInfo: _targetingInfo);

    banner
      ..load()
      ..show();
    banner.dispose();
  }

  showIntersitial() {
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd =
        InterstitialAd(adUnitId: _interAd, targetingInfo: _targetingInfo);

    interstitialAd
      ..load()
      ..show();

    interstitialAd.dispose();
  }
}
```

and showing ads with

```
final AdvertService _advertService = AdvertService();

_advertService.showBanner();

or
_advertService.showIntersitial();
```

What I want to do is make an IAP and remove ads from this user.How can I do it

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways for accomplishing what you're asking.
I suggest you to follow this tutorial:

https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-inapp-purchases/

and to install this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

You will have to enable IAPs on your Google Play Console and/or AppStoreConnect. Remember that using IAPs in an app is subject to Google's and/or Apple's terms of use, so pay attention to those terms.
In addition, if you want to use "Consumables" (an item that can be purchased more that 1 time), you will have to store whether the user has purchased this item in your backend (for example in Firebase Cloud Firestore), since both Apple and Google are only able to store the information regarding if the user has purchased an item, and not how many time he has purchased it.

Let me do a little consideration:
Managing IAPs could be very painful, since it is not the simplest thing to do, especially in Flutter where the native capabilities are not directly managed by the developer. If your goal is ONLY remove the ads if a user wants to pay a little amount of money (like for example 0.99€ or 1.20$), I suggest you to create 2 versions of the app, one with the ads and one without the ads, put the second version on sale on the stores and when the user clicks on "remove ads", open the corresponding store and prompt him to download the "premium version" of your app. You'll save a lot of time and mental health!

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and funny advice. It makes sense to have 2 different versions.